# What is the difference between firebase.auth and firebase.auth()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm doing a codelab for firebase friendlychat web, and there are times when they use firebase.auth and firebase.auth(). I'm confused on the difference between these two, could someone please explain?

Comment: The difference in general is that `firebase.auth` is a reference to the function while `firebase.auth()` *calls* (runs) the function.

Comment: Hey Will. I'm guessing you're referring to this code from [step 7](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/#6): `var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider(); firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);` If that is indeed the code, please include both the snippet and the link in your question, so that folks can see specifically what you're asking about, *and* find more context if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[firebase.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth) by itself is a namespace where other objects can be found.  firebase.auth() as a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#callable) "Gets the [Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) service for the default app or a given app."  As you can see from the API documentation, these objects have different properties and methods.  The first is for interacting with global aspects of the Firebase Auth SDK, and the latter is for interacting with a specifically configured instance of the Auth object where most functionality lives.